# Amazon web services - front facing load balancer security group best practice

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I have a front facing load balancer on my Amazon setup that allows inbound traffic to all ports from all Ips . It was setup like this by EB by default. Is this not insecure? What is the best practice for front facing load balancer security ?

In my particular case I need only traffic for ssl traffic and standard http traffic.
I imagine I should only allow traffic to those ports but I am a little new to server side programming and setup.

Comment: Is EB `elastic Beanstalk`? can you show a screenshot on the inbound setting on that elastic load balancer?

Comment: Yes Elastic beanstalk. Inbound settings are : All traffic, all ports, (source) 0.0.0.0/0. Which is basically wide open.

Comment: port 80 or 22? port 80 has been limited within source IP from other security group. But port 22 is opened to public by default(0.0.0.0/0), that's fine. But if you are not confident for this setting, you can edit it to custom IP or your own IP.

Comment: Sorry by ssl I meant https. I want to allow web traffic over http and https to connect to my EB app so I would have thought that ports and protocols on the loan balancer would be limited to this.. Or perhaps I am misunderstanding the flow here

Answer (score 1):

You can use below flow model for ELB (Elastic Load Balancer):

(1) Https traffic -----> (2) {Front Facing ELB (Public Subnet/internet enabled) SSL aware/URL forwarding to Private VPC}------Http Traffic----> (3) {Internal ELB (Private VPC/Subnet)}

Enable Security on (3) Private VPC/Internal ELB instead doing anything on front facing ELB !!

later, you can also validate http request for authentication once it reached to Private VPC.